# Logic: Prove Distributive Law for Conjunction over Disjunction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am not quite sure how to go about proving the following propositional logic theorem.

Distributive Law for Conjunction over Disjunction:
p ∧ (q ∨ r) ≡ (p ∧ q) ∨ (p ∧ r)

Comment: Did you try using truth tables?

Comment: Hello! I am honestly embarrassed that I have not tried that yet, I was over thinking this one a bit.

Comment: No worries. This happens alot when learning something new :)

Comment: Thank you, So they both have the same outcome for their truth tables, but I am a bit lost on how to explain specifically why with words.

Comment: You can prove it in diferent ways: truth tables, natural deduction, sequent calculus, and many other ways. What kind of proof where you asked to give? Always remember to specify that.

Answer (score 1):

**For the sake of variety, I offer a proof of the syntactic equivalence $p \wedge (q \vee r) \dashv \vdash (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge r)$ via natural deduction below:**

$p \wedge (q \vee r) \vdash (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge r)$

$
\begin{array}{11111}
\{1\} & 1. & p \wedge (q \vee r) & \text{premise} & \\
\{1\} & 2. & p & \text{1 $\wedge$E} & \\
\{1\} & 3. & q \vee r & \text{1 $\wedge$E} & \\
\{4\} & 4. & q & \text{Assumption} & \\
\{1,4\} & 5. & p \wedge q & \text{2,4 $\wedge$I} & \\
\{1,4\} & 6. & (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge r) & \text{5 $\vee$I} & \\
\{7\} & 7. & r & \text{Assumption} & \\
\{1,7\} & 8. & p \wedge r & \text{2,7 $\wedge$I} & \\
\{1,7\} & 9. & (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge r) & \text{8 $\vee$I} & \\
\{1\} & 10. & (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge r) & \text{3,4,6,7,9 $\vee$E} & \square \\
\end{array}
$

$(p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge r) \vdash p \wedge (q \vee r) $

$
\begin{array}{11111}
\{1\} & 1. & (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge r) & \text{premise} & \\
\{2\} & 2. & p \wedge q & \text{Assumption} & \\
\{2\} & 3. & p & \text{2 $\wedge$E} & \\
\{2\} & 4. & q & \text{2 $\wedge$E} & \\
\{2\} & 5. & q \vee r & \text{4 $\vee$I} & \\
\{2\} & 6. & p \wedge (q \vee r) & \text{3,5 $\wedge$I} & \\
\{7\} & 7. & p \wedge r & \text{Assumption} & \\
\{7\} & 8. & p & \text{7 $\wedge$E} & \\
\{7\} & 9. & r & \text{7 $\wedge$E} & \\
\{7\} & 10. & q \vee r & \text{9 $\vee$I} & \\
\{7\} & 11. & p \wedge (q \vee r) & \text{8,10 $\wedge$I} & \\
\{1\} & 12. & p \wedge (q \vee r) & \text{1,2,6,7,11 $\vee$E} & \square \\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Let $A\equiv p\wedge (q \lor r)$ and $B\equiv (p \wedge r) \lor (p \wedge r)$. So, we can see that
\begin{array}{ |c|c|c|c|c|} 
 \hline
 p & q & r & A & B  \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 &  1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \hline
\end{array}
where $1\equiv \text{true}$ and $0\equiv \text{false}$. So, we obtain $A\equiv B$.